# How to get file location path from server but not copy it?

Tags: python, paramiko, pysftp

I have my NAS server located and i am able to get/upload files on it. Now i have suituation where i need to read .png files location from server and pass it on UI thread to show the image. Right now i am only aware of method get which needs local location to save. I don't want file to be save on my local machine but just i shall be able to show that image on my application.

I have gone through this http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.1/api/sftp.html but didn't found relevant method to use

Code is :-

```
import paramiko
paramiko.util.log_to_file(r'D:\TechnoThrone\Builds\paramiko.log')
# Open a transport
host = "stedgela01.TechnoThrone.com"
port = 2222
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
# Auth
password = "xxx"
username = "xxxx"
transport.connect(username = username, password = password)
# Go!
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
# Download
filepath = '/A/B/C/pic_ex.png'
localpath = r'D:\picfolder\pic_ex.png'
sftp.get(filepath, localpath)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get the problem, so I will try to guess a bit.
You should be able to look at content in paths in the remote server without need to download locally the file.
[get](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.1/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.get) is not the right method if you don't want to download because as per documentation:

> `get(remotepath, localpath, callback=None)` Copy a remote file
>   (remotepath) from the SFTP server to the local host as localpath. Any
>   exception raised by operations will be passed through. This method is
>   primarily provided as a convenience.
>
> **Parameters**:    `remotepath` (str) – the remote file to **copy** `localpath`
>   (str) – the destination path on the local host `callback` (callable) –
>   optional callback function (form: func(int, int)) that accepts the
>   bytes transferred so far and the total bytes to be transferred

There are other methods which can get filenames in a remote directory and attributes of those without the need to download.
These are [listdir](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.1/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.listdir), [listdir_attr](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.1/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.listdir_attr) and [listdir_iter](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.1/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.listdir_iter) for example.

For example, `listdir_attr` will

> Return a list containing SFTPAttributes objects corresponding to files
>   in the given path. The list is in arbitrary order. It does not include
>   the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the
>   folder.
>
> The returned SFTPAttributes objects will each have an additional
>   field: longname, which may contain a formatted string of the file’s
>   attributes, in unix format. The content of this string will probably
>   depend on the SFTP server implementation.
>
> Parameters:   path (str) – path to list (defaults to '.')
>   Returns:    list
>   of SFTPAttributes objects

You could use something along these lines:

```
list_png_files = []
for file_attributes in sftp.listdir_attr("remote_path"):
    if file_attributes.filename.endswith('.png'):
        list_png_files.append(file_attributes.filename)
```

Check if it will give you relative or absolute path of course.
Similar you could try with `listdir`, etc.

Comment: I understood your explanation above but my concern is using above technique i can get data like :
/A/B/C/pic_ex1.png
/A/B/C/pic_ex2.png
/A/B/C/pic_ex3.png 
but i can't directly use this path to show on QLabel since it will search on local path. I want this file paths as like link.

Answer (score 0):

```
def _list_remote_dir(self, dir="."):
    sftp_session = self.ssh_session.open_sftp() # ssh_session is paramiko.SSHClient()
    sftp_session.chdir(".")
    cwd = sftp_session.getcwd()
    print(cwd)

    remote_file_attrs = sftp_session.listdir_attr()
    for i in remote_file_attrs:
        logging.info(i.filename)
```

this snipet may help, you got the current working directory, and you got the file name, you can get the abs-path of files on server.